# Stack overflow starting service on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, systemd, docker

Docker service fails to boot with a stackoverflow (see log)

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/dockerd 
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427050817+02:00] libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process  pid=13480
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427221848+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427252917+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427358589+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427395263+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.427482495+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204228e0, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[0000] starting containerd                           revision=468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e version=v1.1.2
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.content.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[0000] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"...  type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
WARN[0000] failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"...  type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
WARN[0000] could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
WARN[0000] could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin  error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"...  type=io.containerd.differ.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"...  type=io.containerd.gc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"...  type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"...  type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"...  type=io.containerd.service.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"...  type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
INFO[0000] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock"
INFO[0000] serving...                                    address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock"
INFO[0000] containerd successfully booted in 0.011705s  
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.468918773+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc4204228e0, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.478059641+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.478109130+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.478176079+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.478207033+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.478306628+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420216860, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.479349936+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420216860, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.484201646+02:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.529886102+02:00] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
WARN[2018-09-19T12:28:25.530461401+02:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period 
WARN[2018-09-19T12:28:25.530493763+02:00] Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime 
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531290994+02:00] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531320383+02:00] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531378011+02:00] ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531402525+02:00] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531475376+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420367310, CONNECTING  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531882385+02:00] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420367310, READY  module=grpc
INFO[2018-09-19T12:28:25.531974913+02:00] Loading containers: start.                   
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x563149e491d3, 0xe)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x83
runtime.newstack()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1054 +0x723
runtime.morestack()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:480 +0x7e
```

/var/log/syslog:

```
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.860950736+02:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=12028
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.861267967+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.861303505+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.861408469+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.861446686+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.861527302+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420380960, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=468a545b9edcd5932818eb9de8e72413e616e86e version=v1.1.2
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37+02:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.014510s"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.903186074+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc420380960, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.912979874+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.913031962+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.913120540+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.913175283+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.913317977+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42022e770, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.916104130+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42022e770, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.920240143+02:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.968229224+02:00" level=info msg="Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.968908861+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.969027089+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.969063772+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970126171+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970163835+02:00" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970242889+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending new addresses to cc: [{unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock 0  <nil>}]" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970283945+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970408299+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007f070, CONNECTING" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970850079+02:00" level=info msg="pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc42007f070, READY" module=grpc
Sep 14 11:51:37 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: time="2018-09-14T11:51:37.970906017+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: fatal error: stack overflow
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: runtime stack:
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: runtime.throw(0x561a1f6941d3, 0xe)
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: #011/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:616 +0x83
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: runtime.newstack()
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: #011/usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1054 +0x723
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: runtime.morestack()
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: #011/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:480 +0x7e
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: goroutine 1 [running]:
Sep 14 11:51:42 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 dockerd[12003]: sort.Search(0x4, 0xc440afc338, 0x0)
```

Same story if I try to reinstall:

```
Setting up docker-ce (18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-09-17 09:32:50 CEST; 17ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3436 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 3436 (code=exited, status=2)

set 17 09:32:51 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
set 17 09:32:51 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
set 17 09:32:51 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
set 17 09:32:51 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess 
returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
```

System info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
$ uname -r
4.15.0-34-generic
$ apt policy docker-ce
docker-ce:
  Installed: 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
  Candidate: 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
  Version table:
 *** 18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable  amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
     18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
     18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu 500
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
        500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe I resolved thanks to the poor ol' docker.io :-)

The problem was caused by a (corrupt?) container; I was not able to remove it because `docker rm` could not start.

installing and purging docker.io triggered [nuke-graph-directory.sh](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/nuke-graph-directory.sh)

```
$ sudo apt purge docker.io
(...)
'/usr/share/docker.io/contrib/nuke-graph-directory.sh' -> '/var/lib/docker/nuke-graph-directory.sh'
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
(Reading database ... 182917 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for docker.io (17.12.1-0ubuntu1) ...

Nuking /var/lib/docker ...
  (if this is wrong, press Ctrl+C NOW!)

+ sleep 10

+ umount -f /var/lib/docker/plugins
+ rm -rf /var/lib/docker/builder /var/lib/docker/buildkit /var/lib/docker/containerd /var/lib/docker/containers /var/lib/docker/image /var/lib/docker/network /var/lib/docker/nuke-graph-directory.sh /var/lib/docker/overlay2 /var/lib/docker/plugins /var/lib/docker/runtimes /var/lib/docker/swarm /var/lib/docker/tmp /var/lib/docker/trust /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Now I can install docker-ce again and start it.

PS I did already `apt purge docker-ce` but it does not purge containers as purging docker.io does